# ActiveWindow.Left with multiple monitors

Tags: excel, vba

I would like the active window of this workbook to be positioned in the upper left hand corner of the active display. This works with one monitor, but not with my configuration of 6-monitors (one video card).

A pic of my monitor setup
[image]

I put the active Excel Window on each display one at a time and ran the following code:

```
Sub Display_WinAnchor()
    ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlNormal
    ActiveWindow.Left = 0
End Sub
```

Monitors 1, 3, 4, 5 are oriented as portrait.
When the code was run on monitors 3 & 5, the window moved to the left side of monitor 3.
When the code was run on monitors 1 & 4, the window moved to the left side of monitor 1.

Monitors 2,6 are oriented as landscape.
When the code was run on monitors 2 & 6, with the active Excel Window on the UPPER half, the window moved to the left side of monitor 3.
When the code was run on monitors 2 & 6, with the active Excel Window on the LOWER half, the window moved to the left side of monitor 1.

I do not use display tiling, I am simply extending the displays in the Windows 10 Display Settings. And it does not seem to be a primary monitor issue.

I can get all the configuration information through code I found here - https://wellsr.com/vba/2019/excel/calculate-screen-size-and-other-display-details-with-vba/

I added the following cases to the code:

```
Case "monitors" 'Number of Monitors
    Result = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CMONITORS)

Case "displaynum" 'Display Device Number
    Result = hMonitor
        
Case "windownum" 'Active Window Number
    Result = hwnd
```

Now, if I run this code...

```
Sub Display_GetSpecs()
   
Debug.Print "Number Of Monitors ="; Screen("monitors")
Debug.Print "Name Of Display = "; Screen("displayname")
Debug.Print "Display Device Number ="; Screen("displaynum")
Debug.Print "Active Window Number ="; Screen("windownum")
Debug.Print "Display Horz PIXEL ="; Screen("pixelsx")
Debug.Print "Display Vert PIXEL ="; Screen("pixelsy")
Debug.Print "Display Horz INCHES ="; Screen("inchesx")
Debug.Print "Display Vert INCHES ="; Screen("inchesy")
Debug.Print "Display Horz POINTS ="; Screen("inchesx") * 72
Debug.Print "Display Vert POINTS ="; Screen("inchesy") * 72

End Sub
```

I get these results...

Number Of Monitors = 6

Name Of Display = \.\DISPLAY4

Display Device Number = 65545

Active Window Number = 526414

Display Horz PIXEL = 1440

Display Vert PIXEL = 2560

Display Horz INCHES = 13.3858267716535

Display Vert INCHES = 23.6220472440945

Display Horz POINTS = 963.779527559055

Display Vert POINTS = 1700.7874015748

Note... "Name Of Display" does not match what Windows 10 Display Settings is showing. Not sure why, but not sure I need it to find a fix to my problem. What I am mostly interested in is the "Display Device Number = 65545"

Is there a way through code to have ActiveWindow.Left work for a specific display? In this example, "Display Device Number = 65545".